# Non-sense error messages for unmet dependencies in Debian Jessie

Tags: debian, apt, dependencies

My problem is not understanding the error messages: It says `I need blah-blah-1.49 (>= 1.49-1) and this is not installable` but I have `blah-blah-1.55` installed already.

I think 1.55 is greater than or equal to 1.49.

Comment: In general, it's more helpful to post actual command output rather than summaries/descriptions/interpretations of the output.

Comment: Non-standard repositories used? That's the root cause I've often seen with these types of errors (and not doing an `update`)

Comment: I didn't post the actual output, because I wanted to start understanding this kind of error messages. Installing the required dependency is not first goal.

Comment: @Xen2050 I'm using Debian Jessie and the repository is for Wheezy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The version is part of the package name in this case (`blah-blah-1.49` vs `blah-blah`). Therefore the package is seen as a different one.

Comment: Which means `(>= 1.49-1...` has no sense? It strictly requires 1.49?

Comment: @ceremcem Maybe, maybe not. Depends on the package in question. See, for example, [apache2.2-bin](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/apache2.2-bin)'s weird version.